# Balanced Parantheses Using Stack

Tags: c, stack

I am trying out a balanced parentheses algorithm using Stacks in C.I have correctly figured out the way when the parantheses are identical (eg "()" or "{}" or "[]") but when they are mixed then I am getting the wrong answer

What's the error in my code ?

int count=0;

typedef struct node{
    struct node *next;
    char data;
}node;

node *top;
node *local;
node *temp;

void create(){
    top=NULL;
}


void push(char data){
    if(top==NULL){
        top=malloc(sizeof(node));
        top->next=NULL;
        top->data=data;
    }
    else{
            temp=malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp->data=data;
            temp->next=top;
            top=temp;
    }
    count++;
}


char pop(){

    local=top;
    if(local==NULL){
        printf("Empty stack\n");
        return;
    }
    else{
        local=local->next;
    }
    //printf("%d\n",top->data );
    return top->data;
        free(top);

        top=local;
        count--;



}

int empty()
    {
        return top==NULL;
    }



int match(char a,char b)
{
    if(a=='[' && b==']')
        return 1;
    if(a=='{' && b=='}')
        return 1;    
    if(a=='(' && b==')')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}/*End of match()*/

int main()
{
    int no, ch, e;
    char str[51];
    scanf("%s",str);
    int z;
    int i;
    char temp;
    int balanced=1;


    z=strlen(str);
     for(i=0;i<z;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]=='(' || str[i]=='{' || str[i]=='[')
            push(str[i]);
        else if(str[i]==')' || str[i]=='}' || str[i]==']')
            {temp=pop();
            if(empty)
                balanced=0;
            if(!match(str[i],temp))
                balanced=0;
            else
                balanced=1;
        }


}
printf("%d\n",balanced );


    return 0;
}

`

Comment: Your `pop()` function looks wrong. None of the statements after the `return` will ever be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring problems in your `pop()` function and rest of your stack code, I would do the balance algorithim like:

```
int balanced = 0;

for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)
{
    if(str[i]=='(' || str[i]=='{' || str[i]=='[')
    {
        push(str[i]);
        ++balanced;
    }
    else if(str[i]==')' || str[i]=='}' || str[i]==']')
    {
        temp = pop();
        if (match(str[i], temp)) --balanced;
    }
}

printf("%d\n", balanced);
```

If `balanced` is 0 at the end then you know all the parentheses balance out. If it is positive then you are missing or have an unbalanced closing parentheses.